# Liquibase-Github actions (Connection timed out error while running liquibase in github actions and while doing diff generation)

Tags: github, mariadb, diff, liquibase

When I'm trying to run Liquibase in Github actions workflows getting the below error

*Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb://10.13.10.2:3306/liquibase_test with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=10.13.10.2)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connect timed out*

not only in github actions when I'm trying to do diff generation in server where liquibase is installed getting the same error.

*Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mariadb://10.13.10.2:3306/liquibase_test with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.  Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=10.13.10.2)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connect timed out*

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: How have you confirmed mariadb is started? How have you determined the IP address?

Comment: MariaDB is in a running state only as it is our DEV SQL Server
I've determined the IP Address with JDBC URL in the GitHub actions workflow